# TypeScript: Populating a Map with Strings and Predicates from String/String and String/Predicate Map

Tags: typescript, dictionary, predicate

I have a `Map` of `string` to `string`:

```js
const strToStr = new Map<string, string>([
    ['foo', 'foo'],
    ['bar', 'qux'],
]);
```

I also have a `Map` of `string` to a predicate function accepting a string:

```js
const strToFnc = new Map<string, (_: string) => boolean>([
    ['baz', (_: string) => true],
    ['buz', (_: string) => false],
]);
```

A third `Map` shall store `string` predicate functions by `string`:

```js
const predicates = new Map<string, (_: string) => boolean>();
```

For the `string`/`string` entries, the predicate function is made up and added:

```js
strToStr.forEach((k) => predicates.set(k, (_) => (k == strToStr.get(k))));
```

This works fine. However, I cannot add the predicates of the other `Map`:

```js
strToFnc.forEach((k) => predicates.set(k, strToFnc.get(k)));
```

```
temp.ts:11:40 - error TS2345: Argument of type '(_: string) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

11 strToFnc.forEach((k) => predicates.set(k, strToFnc.get(k)));
                                          ~

temp.ts:11:56 - error TS2345: Argument of type '(_: string) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

11 strToFnc.forEach((k) => predicates.set(k, strToFnc.get(k)));
                                                          ~

Found 2 errors in the same file, starting at: temp.ts:11
```

Since `strToFnc.get('...')` returns a predicate function, why does this operation not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`forEach()` method of `Map` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) doesn't behave the way you think it does.  If you look at [its typings](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/d4fbc9b57d9aa7d02faac9b1e9bb7b37c687f6e9/src/lib/es2015.collection.d.ts#L10):

```
interface Map<K, V> {
  forEach(callbackfn: (value: V, key: K, map: Map<K, V>) => void, thisArg?: any): void;
}
```

the callback's first parameter will receive the *value* from the map, and its *second* parameter receives the key.

Looks like you're accidentally using the value instead of the key.  Assuming that you really intended to use the key, you'd need something like

```
strToStr.forEach((_, k) => predicates.set(k, (_) => (k == strToStr.get(k))));
strToFnc.forEach((_, k) => predicates.set(k, strToFnc.get(k)!));
```

Of course you don't need `get()` in there since you'd also have the value:

```
strToStr.forEach((v, k) => predicates.set(k, (_) => (k == v)));
strToFnc.forEach((v, k) => predicates.set(k, v));
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBNBOAVEBlK8YF4ZgKYHcYBZAQwAcAeBASzAHMAaOdWugPgAoBtAKBn5hcA5ADMQIIU1HihAXQZ8BwgEYl4kmEICOAVwAechbICUAbh4XQkWAmQAxMMCw4CxclRb0mHAPoAuZnhWYyw2GGVxABtcEjBOXgFBIVUALw1fAJp6EMww9B1ceUV+FR00739A4NCYERJIiEKjMwseK2gYMnhcABNqYBIoXAhnPEJSSizGGAyq7JqIkGjYzhaLW1R0ADoxeABREmAACw5fJgBrHLCu3v7B4a3GqA5ziquZ86xsDbR4LbpcM9LsYQeYNg5gDsQPtDiczjBLjUbn0BkMII9AS8mODHP9MZcAISg9boZC-KEw46nABuF3eyLuaIxQLeNReXxg1JBLRxkN2BypHFpCPp3RR93RTyxnOJQA)

Comment: Thanks, this behavior is really surprising to me, because in most languages/libraries/frameworks, the key always comes first.